# “The spider's legs bent in upon its body”

Tags: sentence-meaning, harry-potter

What does the phrase in bold mean?

> At once, **the spider’s legs bent in upon its body;** it rolled over and began to twitch horribly, rocking from side to side.

*I think*: The spider's legs bent inward on top of its body not under its body. I found this sentence in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

I want to know what this process looks like. (the way its legs are bent, the shape it gets into. Basically, what a native speaker would understand when he or she reads it.)

Comment: My immediate image is of a dead spider on its back, with its legs curled in, though the surrounding context may indicate otherwise.

Comment: You can see the movie's representation of it [here](https://youtu.be/2htMZ3Vmc8w?t=207).

Comment: So the Movie's representation is wrong

Comment: A movie doesn't accurately represent every small detail from a book. You should be able to imagine what it would be like if your legs were bent in underneath you, and imagine a spider doing similar. But I don't suppose native readers give the phrase much thought, other than to imagine the spider is rolled up or tucked in or otherwise made small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, I think it's fair to assume that the author intends the reader to have only a basic understanding of how a spider moves. Therefore, I visualize this sentence as a spider with its legs folded under the body not over the body since a spider's legs don't naturally move in that way. Here's a picture similar to how I would visualize it:[image]